# ¿Cómo ejecutar consultas usando group_concat en Laravel 5 usando Eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

Tengo la siguiente tabla **Abilities**

**Id**, **Name**, **Title**, **Json**
1,  edit, Gestionar_Usuario, Null
2,  create, Gestionar_Usuario, Null
3,  delete, Gestionar_Usuario, Null

Y deseo obtener las distintas operaciones que hay en la tabla según el título Gestionar_Usuario, es decir (edit, create,delete en este caso)

Con MySql pude ejecutar esta consulta y me devolvió el resultado esperado

```
select id,title, GROUP_CONCAT(`name`) as `name`, json, entity_type, entity_id, created_at, updated_at from abilities
```

[image: Imagen del Resultado de Ejecutar la Consulta anterior]

Y al llevarlo a Laravel en la misma clase Ability.php que extiende de Model hice lo siguiente:

```
public static function getAll(){
    $raw = DB::raw('id,title, GROUP_CONCAT(`name`) as `name`, json, entity_type, entity_id, created_at, updated_at');
    return self::select($raw)->groupBy('title')->get();
}
```

Pero al ejecutar el código me da el siguiente error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'khamaro.abilities.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select *,GROUP_CONCAT(`name`) as `name` from `abilities` group by `title`)'
```

Sin embargo en MYSQL funciona perfectamente. Ahora para solucionar el error puedo hacer 2 cosas: Quitar todos los campos del select excepto el 'name' que es el que agrupo, o añado al ->groupBy todos los que faltan, dicho sea de paso no devuelve lo que deseo.

Comment: En la consulta de "MySql" puro (sin Eloquent), veo que no hay un group by, ¿es correcto?

Comment: Si es correcto pero al llevarlo a Eloquent me exige que ponga el group by

Answer (score 1):

Prueba reemplazando esta linea

```
    $raw = DB::raw('id,title, GROUP_CONCAT(`name`) as `name`, json, entity_type, entity_id, created_at, updated_at');
return self::select($raw)->groupBy('title')->get()
```

por esto

```
    $raw = DB::raw('SELECT id,title, GROUP_CONCAT(`name`) as `name`, json, entity_type, entity_id, created_at, updated_at');
return self::select($raw)->get()->groupBy('title');
```